# Create a Map<string, Set<String>>, where 1st string is the unique value

Tags: apex

I have a requirement, where I have to fecth record and put it in a Map.
I have a custom Object `My_Object__c` and it has 2 fields : `child_Name__c` and `Parent_Name__c`.

What I did, I query from the `My_Object__c` and put the record in `Map<String, My_Object__c> dataMap`.

Now I want to store data in a Map. `Map<String, Set<String>> secondMap`// 1st String : `parent_Name__c` and 2nd String : `child_Name__c`. where 1st string is the unique value.

Table will look like below.

`child_Name__c  Parent_Name__c
A               AB
B               AB
C               AB
K               BC
F               BC`

`dataMap :[AB : {A,B,C}, BC : {k,F}]`

This is what I did :

**Class **

```
dateMap = new Map<String, My_Object__c >();
for(My_Object__c obj : [select Id,child_Name__c,Parent_Name__c
                         from My_Object__c 
                        ]) {
    dateMap.put(obj.child_Name__c, obj );   
}
```

By using this dataMap, how I will create the `Map<String, Set<String>> secondMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not require to use first map i.e datamap.
You can create 2nd map directly as follows:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> secondMap = new Map<String, Set<String>>(); 
for(My_Object__c obj : [select Id,child_Name__c,Parent_Name__c from My_Object__c]) {
    if(!secondMap.containsKey(obj.parent_Name__c)){
         secondMap.put(obj.Parent_Name__c, new Set<String>{obj.child_Name__c});

    }else{
         secondMap.get(obj.Parent_Name__c).add(obj.child_Name__c);
    }
}
```